# How to select data using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am using spring mvc with Hibernate. I write insert using Hibernate but I couldn't find way to write search data from my database. I've inserted a process I do like in the example below. How do I write the select using the SessionFactory Autowired object?

I want to do `select * from employee where username='hesh'` using Hibernate.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void AddEmployee(Employee employee) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);  

}}
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method:

```
@Override
public List listEmployee(String username) throws Exception{
    Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Employee.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));  
 criteria.setMaxResults(10);//optionally set max return rows.       
 return criteria.list();
}}
```